# Angular directives: can we use '_' instead of '-' for separating words in directives

Tags: angularjs, haml

This is just a quick question regarding AngularJS syntax. Do these following codes **equivalent** and can be used **interchangeably**?

```
<div ng-class="!!navigation.path ? '' : 'dropdown'"></div>
```

and

```
<div ng_class="!!navigation.path ? '' : 'dropdown'"></div>
```

This is important because if we write Angular templates using HAML, I can do this:

```
%div{ng_class: "!!navigation.path ? '' : 'dropdown'"}
```

instead of this:

```
%div{"ng-class" => "!!navigation.path ? '' : 'dropdown'"}
```

Comment: You can imagine it's not really "important" for the Angular developers to let you save a few keystrokes when using a HTML shorthand they don't have anything to do with. Personally I'd consider it a flaw in HAML's syntax if it makes using hyphenated attribute names a chore, seeing as that's the de facto standard convention. (`data-*` attributes in the spec could also be construed as an "official endorsement" of a sort.)

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I would say that they aren't equivalent and the second one is invalid. But, much to my surprise, after doing a quick test it seems that both are valid and functional, except for the `ng-app` directive. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/QYJHv/) jsFiddle illustrates it.

<s>This is not documented, though. What the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile.directive.Attributes) says is:</s>

> (...) The normalization is needed since all of these are treated as equivalent in Angular:
>
> ```
> <span ng:bind="a" ng-bind="a" data-ng-bind="a" x-ng-bind="a">
> ```

That said, I think it's safer if you stick to the docs and pick one of the official formats in order to keep you code future-proof.

**Update**

I've just found out the following in the [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Directives have camel cased names such as ngBind. The directive can be
>   invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these
>   special characters :, -, or _. Optionally the directive can be
>   prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant. Here
>   is a list of some of the possible directive names: ng:bind, ng-bind,
>   ng_bind, x-ng-bind and data-ng-bind.

So it seems that you can safely use an underscore as a word separator in a directive's name - except for `ng-app`.